# Can you use the Google Photo API with the Google picker?

Tags: google-api, picasa, google-picker, google-photos-api

My understanding is that the Google Picker can be used to select "Picasa" photos and albums. However, since the Picasa API has now been shutdown, the ids returned by the picker are completely useless (at least as far as doing anything with the returned IDs goes).

There is a Google Photo API but I'm not aware of a Picker that returns IDs compatible with it.

So, does anyone know of a way to use the (very pretty and functional) Google Picker (technically for Picasa but still shows Google photo albums) with the Google Photos API?

Perhaps some way to exchange the Picasa IDs for new Google API ones?

Comment: I think about this matter, there is no declaration yet about the compatibility of ID's of Picasa API and Google Photo API. If you have to check [this forum](https://developers.google.com/picker/forum), we are still waiting for the answer from Google. Also, reading thoroughly the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/3.0/developers_guide_migration) could also help. The best thing to do now is to wait for the update from google.