Trying to implement google photos picker api
In my next.js application, I'm trying to implement the Google Photos library API. But in this case, I want to get the Google Photos library picker just like the Google Drive picker. But when I try to open the picker I see this error.

It also generates an access token and also gives array-type data if I use it on axios api method. But I want it to be in a picker  if possible .
This is my code. Correct me if I'm doing it wrong.
const GooglePhotosPicker = ({ onPick }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadGisClient = () => {
      window.onGoogleLibraryLoad = () => {
        const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
          client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
          scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly",
          callback: (tokenResponse) => {
            if (tokenResponse.error) {
              console.error(
                "Error obtaining access token:",
                tokenResponse.error
              );
              return;
            }
            initializePicker(tokenResponse.access_token);
          },
        });

        document.getElementById("authorize_button").onclick = () => {
          client.requestAccessToken();
        };
      };

      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/api.js";
      script.onload = () => {
        gapi.load("picker", { callback: onPickerApiLoad });
        window.onGoogleLibraryLoad();
      };
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    };

    loadGisClient();
  }, []);

  const onPickerApiLoad = () => {
    console.log("Picker API loaded");
  };

  const initializePicker = (accessToken) => {
    const picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
      .addView(google.picker.ViewId.PHOTOS)
      .setOAuthToken(accessToken)
      .setDeveloperKey(process.env.KEY)
      .setCallback(pickerCallback)
      .build();
    picker.setVisible(true);
  };

  const pickerCallback = (data) => {
    if (data.action === google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
      const file = data.docs[0];
      onPick(file);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button id="authorize_button">Pick a Photo from Google Photos</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function Page() {
  const handlePickedPhoto = (photo) => {
    console.log("Selected photo:", photo);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
      <GooglePhotosPicker onPick={handlePickedPhoto} />
    </div>
  );
}

and yes console.google.com project does also have the permission of this scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly
How to fix this issue?

Not sure why you're getting downvoted. I'm getting the exact same error. Looking at the API, google.picker.ViewId.PHOTOS is deprecated but there seems to be no replacement or documentation about this. The whole Google Picker API seems incredibly poorly documented, even though Google is kicking us off the now restricted drive.readonly scope, and maybe soon also the "sensitive" photoslibrary.readonly scope. There's this SO but no conclusion also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55326819/can-you-use-the-google-photo-api-with-the-google-picker
